# Mouse position is offset in MonoGame

Tags: c#, monogame

So I'm implementing shooting in my game, but when I resize the window or move (because of my camera) the mouse position gets offset and the shots obviously don't hit where I want them to, and I don't know how to fix it. Here's the relevant code:

Shot.cs

```
public class Shot : Sprite {

    private float Speed = 500;
    private Vector2 Dir;
    private Vector2 Velocity;

    public Shot(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        : base(texture) {
        this.Position = position;
        this.Dir = Input.GetMousePos() - Position;
    }

    void Start() {

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
        var delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        Dir.Normalize();
        Velocity = Dir * Speed;
        Position += Velocity * delta;
    }
}
```

Camera.cs GetTransform() (please note that I didn't write this)

```
public Matrix GetTransform(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice) {
    transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0)) *
                                         Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
                                         Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
                                         Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 1));
    return transform;
}
```

spriteBatch.Begin();

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, camera.GetTransform(GraphicsDevice));
```

Also wanted to add that this isn't a shooting specific problem, the position also gets offset when I try to drag a GUI window, so I think I need to do modify my GetMousePosition method, but I'm not sure how.

EDIT: Here's GetMousePos()

```
public static Vector2 GetMousePos() {
    return new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
}
```

Comment: as already mentioned, can you please add your `GetMousePos` method? Thanks

Comment: I did some more googling and got it to work using this answer:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21681/how-to-get-mouse-position-relative-to-the-map